# Do I consider decimal point of px in media query?

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I have been using `@media` to query screen widths like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 1023px) {
  color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  color: blue;
}
```

But, I just noticed if someone uses a device that is 767.5px (such as a zoomed-in viewport), than this code won't work.

Is it the right thinking to consider decimal-point screen dimensions?

I already know this workaround:

```
/* tablet */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  color: red;
}

/* web */
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  color: blue;
}

/* bigweb */
@media (min-width: 1440px) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

But I don't like to use this because media query cascading can be confusing. CSS only meant for mobile devices will apply for wider devices this way, if I forget to specifically override it in the later `@media` rules.

Comment: I think you don't need because screen don't have a half pixel(value in decimal) either it has a complete or none.

Comment: `@media (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 1023px)` will never become true.

Comment: Please could you check your example code because the first media query makes no sense. A viewport width cannot be both at most 768px and at least 1023px. Put up an example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Rana - Sub-pixel viewport sizes are most definitely a thing when zoom levels are not 100%, and the problem that the OP alludes to but explains poorly is real. However, the OP already knows the solution, but it confuses them. They just need more practice.

Comment: Ohh yes @Alohci, forget `media` are applied to zoomed page also

Comment: Oh I wrote wrong code. But I understand all now. Thank you

Comment: I edited the question with common English and illustrative details. @Alohci I disagree that "they just need more practice" is an effective solution: in a more complicated layout where certain elements are shown or hidden depending on mobile or desktop viewport, you have to explicitly pay attention and make sure rules only intended for mobile are *specifically overridden* in desktop (i.e. later queries). It's a workable paradigm, but provides a complicated solution to a comparatively simple problem, "how do I independently style two width ranges without worrying about decimals between them?"

Answer (score 2):

#### The current situation

Some references online indicate there is not a generally "perfect" solution for this problem - today, anyway! Here is example CSS from [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/):

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575.98px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) { ... }
```

As you can see, they just use values which are *close* to the upper limit but not quite equal.

And here's what Bootstrap says about this example (emphasis mine):

> Note that **since browsers do not currently support [range context queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#range-context),** we work around the limitations of [min- and max- prefixes](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-min-max) and viewports with fractional widths (which can occur under certain conditions on high-dpi devices, for instance) by using **values with higher precision for these comparisons.**

The links above are from W3C from the official [Media Queries Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/) specification, and include more illustrative commentary (emphasis mine):

> While this ensures that the two sets of styles don’t apply simultaneously when the viewport width is 320px, it does not take into account the possibility of fractional viewport sizes which can occur as a result of non-integer pixel densities (e.g. on high-dpi displays or as a result of zooming/scaling). **Any viewport widths that fall between 320px and 321px will result in none of the styles being applied.**
>
> **One approach to work around this problem is to increase the precision of the values used for the comparison.** Using the example above, changing the second comparison value to 320.01px significantly reduces the change that a viewport width on a device would fall between the cracks.

#### The future: Range Syntax

All hope is not lost! As Bootstrap mentioned, Media Queries Level 4 defines **range context queries**. W3C give a straightforward example:

> However, in these situations, range context queries (which are not limited to “>=” and “<=” comparisons) offer a more appropriate solution:
>
> ```
> @media (width <= 320px) { /* styles for viewports <= 320px */ }
> @media (width > 320px) { /* styles for viewports > 320px */ }
> ```

Corresponding example code for your question would be:

```
/* tablet */
@media ( 768px <= width < 1024px) {
  color: red;
}

/* web */
@media (1024px <= width < 1440px) {
  color: blue;
}

/* bigweb */
@media (1440px <= width) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Support for range context queries is limited, but gradually expanding. See [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-media-range-syntax) for the latest details; basically, the latest of all major browsers except Safari support it, with Chrome and derivative browsers (Edge, Opera) gaining support just recently in August 2022, and Firefox having support back since October 2018.

Unfortunately (but not too surprisingly), there don't seem to be any "polyfills" or post-processing code which would allow you to write future-ready `min <= width < max`-style queries today, and automatically convert it to `.98px`-style code in build output. If you're familiar with build systems and CSS post-processing, it may not be difficult to write such a system for your specific project.

If you don't use a build system, you are out of luck *for now,* but wider support for range context queries may arrive in the near future, so keep your eye on the horizon!